# Ограничить доступ к странице WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно закрыть одну страницу от неавторизованных пользователей, посредством редиректа на страницу авторизации. Работаю на WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию `auth_redirect()`, она выполнит ровно то, что вам необходимо ([документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/))

Ну либо более сложный путь: для проверки, авторизован ли пользователь, используйте функцию `is_user_logged_in()`, она вернёт `false`, если пользователь не залогинился ([тут документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)), далее выполняйте редирект куда вам необходимо